# Using filter on /me/joinedTeams not working

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm implementing a search for a user's joined Teams unsing Microsoft Graph. The idea is to make a call to `/beta/me/joinedTeams` and use a `?$filter=startswith(description,'searchterm')` filter.

So for example when I try the request `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/joinedTeams?$filter=startswith(description,'Business')` in the [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) it ignores the filter and I get these results:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#groups",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "02bd9fd6-8f93-4758-87c3-1fb73740a315",
            "displayName": "HR Taskforce",
            "description": "Welcome to the HR Taskforce team.",
            "isArchived": false
        },
        {
            "id": "13be6971-79db-4f33-9d41-b25589ca25af",
            "displayName": "Business Development",
            "description": "Welcome to the BizDev team.",
            "isArchived": false
        },
        {
            "id": "8090c93e-ba7c-433e-9f39-08c7ba07c0b3",
            "displayName": "X1050 Launch Team",
            "description": "Welcome to the team that we've assembled to launch our product.",
            "isArchived": false
        }
    ]
}
```

Am I doing something wrong with my request?

Comment: Are you authenticated in Graph Explorer? In the upper left-hand column, look for "You are currently using a sample account." I get the same result set without any filters applied (https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/joinedTeams).

Comment: No, I'm not authenticated. But it makes no difference whether I'm authenticated or not, I have the same effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your request is right, but the joinedTeams does not support filtering or ordering results. So although we pass the filter/orderby parameter, when Microsoft Graph sees a query parameter it doesn't expect, it simply ignores the unknown filter/orderby parameter and returns an unfiltered/default-sorted result.

I have tried the api with odata query parameters for trial O365 account and real account.

> https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters
>
> Not all parameters are supported across all Microsoft Graph APIs, and
> support might differ significantly between the v1.0 and beta
> endpoints.

The only suggestion for you is to vote up the existing feature request in [User Voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) or submit a new one.

Comment: I know this answer is correct. but how did you know that  joinedTeams does not support that filtering ?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for pointing this out. As Seiya points out, /me/joinedTeams does not support the OData query parameters. The [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/user_list_joinedteams) suggested otherwise, I've made a doc fix that should propagate in the next day or two.